# pack float into two bytes in WebGL2

Tags: glsl, webgl2

I have deferred MRT render written in WebGL2. In one of standard (non float) destination textures I have two available byte components, say x and y. I want to pack and lately unpack a floating value with a range [0..100].

How to implement conversion forth and back between between float and two bytes components preserving as much precision as possible?

Comment: WHAT? That other answer seems wrong for this question. This question is about WebGL2 and in WebGL2 there are difference answers

Comment: really? can you suggest and write an answer?